# Subdivision Surface mesh weird vertex behaviour

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm modeling a character and I've noticed some weird vextex behaviour that is deforming the mesh with the subdivision surface on it.

[image]
[image]

The vertex causing this deformity seems to bem "stacked" on the mesh, I tried to remove them and remake the part of the mesh but when I do this the vextex next the removed part keep the same behaviour, so I just pull the problem ahead...

Normal Behaviour
[image: Normal Behaviour]
Weird Behaviour
[image: Weird Behaviour]

[image]

Comment: could you please share the part of the mesh where there's the problem? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I added the mesh in the post, thanks for answering!

Comment: Just to inform, I used blender 2.8 to make this mesh

Comment: yes, I opened it with 2.8, I think you have a normal issue, see my answer below and tell me if it fixes your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a normal issue, you need to select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate. Also you'll have to disable the *Subsurf Clipping* option, select all the boarder vertices, move them a bit on the X axis to create a gap, then reactivate *Clipping* and move back the vertices so that it sticks correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked greatly! The clipping was a little tricky to fix after the recalculation, but with your help I could do it!!